# spring boot spring data jpa multiple datasource to execute same service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement where I need to fetch data from one MySQL DB table, and this data needs to be fetched from multiple MySQL DBs. So the code needs to be same just datasource needs to be different.
I want my application to be generic so that in case there is new DB is required we just have to put the entries into application.properties and no more code changes are required. We can do something with for loop etc.

I am able to do multiple connections by creating different beans like:

```
@Bean(name = "mysqlDb")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_mysql")
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "mysqlJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("mysqlDb") DataSource dsMySQL) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsMySQL);
    }
```

But I will have to put code with every bean, which I want to ignore as the datasource beans creation should be dynamic and I just need to put the db properties in application.properties.

Please let me know if there is any way to do so.

Comment: _But I will have to put code with every bean_, what do you mean by that? Can you describe your problem statement more.

Comment: I meant whenever I need to put a new datasource I will have to create bean for it as mentioned in the code, and also I need to use that bean instance for service call. Wherever my requirement is that same code needs to be invoked with multiple datasources, and just have to add datasource properties in application.properties and the existing code will work with so many no of connections

Comment: So, at any point of time, do you need to connect to multiple datasources or a single datasource?

Comment: do you want to use multiple datasources at once?

Comment: At any point I would be connected to single datasource, it will be like connect to DB1 fetch data, connect to DB2 fetch data, connect to DB3 fetch data etc

Comment: then use `profiles` in spring

Comment: No, cant use spring, ex - I have to call one service and that service will call dao layer for DB1, then dao layer for DB2, then dao layer for DB3 and then the data is manipulated for all 3 DBs in service layer

Comment: what about this "At any point I would be connected to single datasource"

Comment: I see, you need to use AbstractRoutingDataSource. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source

Comment: Thanks @Bala, but it seems that will have to make changes in code too, do you think is there any other way where we don't require code changes and can add db details

Comment: You need to create a datasource for each database, and that means a new bean. Spring helps you with @ConfigurationProperties, check this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: Too complex use case, you might need to look into programmatic bean registration and construct beans based on your properties. https://spring.io/blog/2017/03/01/spring-tips-programmatic-bean-registration-in-spring-framework-5

Comment: If I create multiple beans as mentioned above any idea how to use all beans in for loop to call same method. I don't want to change further code with using qualifier